# IIS 7.5 Virtual Directory to Mapped Drive

Tags: iis, networking, windows-server-2008

I have an S: which is connected via a username that exists both on server1 & server2.

The mapped drive works fine.

I connect this as a virtual directory called config in IIS it connects and works fine. I can see in content view the files in the mapped drive.

When I attempt to browse to one of these files it gets an error 500

http://www.mydomain.com/config/file.html

file.html is there

I've done this before, Im sure its a permission or security issue somehow, but I cant work it out

500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Comment: Was the folder share created for the same user as the AppPool user your site runs under?  If not it wouldn't be able to see it AFAIK.

Comment: Im not sure what an AppPool user is or where I see which user my site is running under can you clarify.

Comment: I tried changing the virtual directory from a mapped drive S: to a UNC \\server\path and while it all still seems ok in IIS I get 404 errors trying to get to any of the content.

Comment: When your website runs it will run under a particular AppPool.  That AppPool will run as a particular user - mapped drives are normally only visible to the user who created them, so unless your website runs under the same username as the user who created the mapped drive you won't see it.  That user will also need permissions to access whatever the folder is on the remote box.

Comment: I dont know where to see which user or apppool this is run under to try this out.

Comment: If you check the AppPools you can see the user your app pool is running as.  You can then check the permissions for that user against the network share.  I hesitate to suggest it (this is **dangerous**) but for testing purposes if you grant 'Everyone' access to your folder share on the remote computer can you get through without a 404?

Comment: Ok, That was a good idea, Adding Everbody still doesn't work. I'm thinking it's perhaps a firewall issue. No idea what ports / services would be blocked.

Comment: No, its not the firewall, I turned it off and it still doesnt work, im stumped.

Comment: When I browse locally, I see more info

Comment: HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

Comment: Actually since its just a comment, I cant accept it :(

Comment: Post this resolution as a new answer as yourself, and then mark it as answer is also acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was two part.

Part one I was simply browsing the website, I wasn't using https and thus I was getting a different IIS site that didn't have the virtual directory.

Part two was I was using ColdFusion attempting to run a .cfm from the virtual directory, even with the correct website, it still got an error 404.

The resolution for this was to ensure the ColdFusion service was run as Administrator rather than LocalSystem and all was good.

Just for everyones reference, if you create the same username / password on both servers, share using that username, connect using UNC path and that username and it will work, no special permissions or anything.

Thanks to Karl & Lex for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Give up mapped drives please,

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/207671

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257174

Comment: Ok, As I said above I changed it to a UNC when I add the virtual directory I specify connect as user, that user has been created on both servers it connects and verifies the location two green ticks. Yet I get 404 error trying to access anything.